# convert string value to Boolean (true or false)

Tags: javascript, string, boolean

i.e. I have data like the below:

```
[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz3","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz4","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz5","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz6","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz7",...........................}]
```

What is a good way find and convert my "*false*" to `false` for instance as I am needing a boolean `true` or `false` without quotes.

I am getting the data like below:

```
  $.getJSON("./coolBeans.json", function(json) {
            data = json[key];
            console.log(data);         
   ...................
```

Comment: Assuming the string is in `s`, you could do `JSON.parse(s)` which would work since `false` and `true` are valid JSON representations for the corresponding boolean values, or simply `s === 'true'` (which will also be true/false accordingly). This is assuming that the strings can _only_ contain `true` or `false`.

Comment: of course, the ideal solution is to fix the source data

Comment: Have you considered making an attempt to compare the value against `'false'`? Then you can use that result

Comment: what about "checked" is not "true" or "false", but "something else" ?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```js
var str = '[{"id":"slz1","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz2","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz3","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz4","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz5","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz6","checked":"false"},{"id":"slz7","checked":"true"}]'

var res = str.replace(/\"false\"|\"true\"/gi, function (x) { // Checks for any "false" or "true" string, replace global and case insensitive
  return x.substr(1, x.length-2); // skip first '"' and last '"' char
}); 

document.write( res );
```

Result

> [{"id":"slz1","checked":**false**},{"id":"slz2","checked":**false**},{"id":"slz3","checked":**false**},{"id":"slz4","checked":**false**},{"id":"slz5","checked":**false**},{"id":"slz6","checked":**false**},{"id":"slz7",...........................}]

Then process your data.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just using a `map` and a `condition` on `checked` key should be easy enough:

```js
var data = 
  [ { "id": "slz1", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz2", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz3", "checked": "true"  } 
  , { "id": "slz4", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz5", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz6", "checked": "false" } 
  ];

var res = data.map((val) => {
  val.checked = val.checked == "false" ? false : true;
  return val;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @MisterJojo  the OP has mentioned about the checked being a string and wanting to convert it to boolean specifically. We can use an `if else` or ternary or any expression for condition can't we?

Comment: in this case why don't you code this `val.checked = (('val.checked=="false"?false:true)?false:true)?false:true;`

Comment: @MisterJojo, why don't you use `val.checked= val.checked=='true'` ? remove that `!` :D . Thanks for the downvote, should have kept your comment as well

Comment: @MisterJojo, wait so you are saying that your code checks for "Something else" condition??

Comment: I explained in my answer why I did it.
When OP deigns to answer my question I will see if I have to correct it

Answer (score 0):

Slight correction on the other answer to account for both true and false scenario

```
var arrayObj = 
  `[ { "id": "slz1", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz2", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz3", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz4", "checked": "true"  } 
  , { "id": "slz5", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz6", "checked": "false" } 
  , { "id": "slz7", "checked": "false" } 
  ]` 

var parse = JSON.parse(arrayObj);
    
var newArray = parse.slice();
newArray.forEach(val => {
  val.checked = val.checked == 'true'? true: false
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var arrayObj = `[{
                "id":"slz1",
                "checked":"false"
                },{
                  "id":"slz2",
                  "checked":"false"
                },{
                  "id":"slz3",
                  "checked":"false"
                },{
                  "id":"slz4",
                  "checked":"false"
                },{
                  "id":"slz5",
                  "checked":"false"
                },{
                  "id":"slz6",
                  "checked":"false"
                },{
                  "id":"slz7",
                  "checked": "true"
                }]`;


var parsed = JSON.parse(arrayObj);
parsed.forEach(val => {
  if (val.checked === 'false') {
    val.checked = false;
  } else if (val.checked === 'true) {
    val.checked = true;
  }
});
console.log(parsed);
```

I parse that JSON array of object. Loop through every object in the array and check the string value of the checked property. make a conditional statement that if the value of checked is a string 'false' then set it to Boolean false, If its a string 'true' then set it to Boolean true.

Hope it help.